# Strapi losing public role permissions when starting

Tags: strapi

I have a strapi application, when I use develop and set up my api for public role everything works fine. Then I use plesk to execute a js file server.js with the following script.

```
const strapi = require('@strapi/strapi');

// start strapi application
strapi().start();
```

so long so good. The moment that i query my api suddenly my permissions are removed from `up_permissions_role_links` I can't seem to find any reason for it or any information about it. I have tried 100 times always the same. the second I run the node server.js command and then after I go to the API url my permissions dissapear.

Any information on how to solve this would be appreciated